# When working with Mergesort, quicksort etc, is O(n log n) base 2, or base 10?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, quicksort

I'm a little confused about big O notations.

Let's say I'm working with an array of 16 elements and trying to do a QuickSort.

A QuickSort's Average case is O(n log n) and its worst case is O(n^2)

I assumed it would be log base 2 since we're working with computers (binary).  But I've also heard you could use base 10 and get the same complexity.

I figured it would be 16*log2*16 == 16 * 4 = 64 comparisons at O(n log n).

At O(n^2) == 16^2 ==  256 comparisons at its worst case.

Do I have the right idea?  And as a general rule, should I be using base 10 or base 2?

Comment: the base does not matter. computer scientists tend to use base 2 (or 10) logarithms, where as mathematicians tend to use base e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as big-Oh notation is concerned, the base of the logarithms doesn't make any real difference, because of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base) important property, called `Change of Base`.

According to this property, changing the base of the logarithm, in terms of big-oh notation, only affects the complexity by a constant factor.

What you should use as a general rule... well, it depends.

Mergesort halves the array, so you should think of it as a base-2 logarithm.

The complexity of algorithms dealing with binary trees made out of `n` elements, should use base-2 logarithms, but if dealing with ternary trees made out of `n` elements it should be base-3 logarithms.

It's all a matter of counting correctly.

So the only general rule is the change of base property.

Comment: Oh ok thanks.  Most of the stuff I'm dealing with now (Merge sort, Quicksort, Selection sort, bubble sort heap sort etc) is going to be base-2 because of binary?  But if I were to encounter a ternary tree or even bigger, I'd have to adjust the base?

Comment: @user3577397 The base is adjusted to the problem, but the result in big-oh notation won't really change, because of this property.